# How to limit the number of iterations the pam function from cluster library does?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

## How to reduce the number of iterations for PAM clustering algorithm in the cluster package?

I am trying to produce a couple of plots showing how pam works, so trying to reduce the number of iterations to 2. I have cloned the [cluster repo](https://github.com/cran/cluster.git) to my working directory, where I have edited the pam.q file (directory ./cluster/R) for nMax to be equal to 2.

```
# original
nMax <- 65536 # 2^16 (as 1+ n(n-1)/2 must be < max_int = 2^31-1)

# modified 
nMax <- 2
```

However, even with no changes applied to the original file, pam algorithm fails to run. If I load it by typing in library(cluster) instead, it works as supposed, but this way I have no ability to manipulate the number of iterations.

Sample code of what I'm trying to achieve is displayed below:

```
# -- Working code --
library(datasets)
data(iris)
library(cluster)

df <- data.frame(iris$Petal.Length, iris_modified$Petal.Width)
pam.res <- pam(df, k = 2)
pam.res

# -- Failing Code --
library(datasets)
data(iris)
source("./cluster/R/pam.q")

df <- data.frame(iris$Petal.Length, iris_modified$Petal.Width)
pam.res <- pam(df, k = 2)
pam.res
```

This is the error I'm getting, when running the "Failing Code" above:

> Error in pam(clust_ex, k = 2) : object 'cl_Pam' not found

I expect the same output as for the working code, when I am linking the pam.q file directly instead of loading the library.

Is there something I'm not doing quite right in the way I import the q file? Or is there another way to change the number of iterations the pam algorithm performs?

Answer (score 0):

Nmax is the maximum number of objects.

Its not the maximum number of iterations.

Is also not sufficient to just modify the .q file.

It's probably easier to do this with ELKI...

Comment: could you elaborate please? I can't find a package called elki. I'd be grateful if you could provide a short example.

Comment: There is life outside of R, too.